# I'm using amazon linux and trying to install mysql in ec2, but I keep getting the error "GPG key a is already installed" It happens

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am currently trying to install mysql in ec2, but the "GPG key" error keeps occurring.

### - errormessage

```
[root ec2-user]# sudo yum install mysql-community-server
Last metadata expiration check: 3:41:39 ago on Thu Jan 25 23:25:24 2024.
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================
 Package                             Arch        Version              Repository              Size
===================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-community-server              x86_64      8.0.36-1.el9         mysql80-community       49 M
Installing dependencies:
 mysql-community-client              x86_64      8.0.36-1.el9         mysql80-community      3.4 M
 mysql-community-client-plugins      x86_64      8.0.36-1.el9         mysql80-community      1.4 M
 mysql-community-common              x86_64      8.0.36-1.el9         mysql80-community      556 k
 mysql-community-icu-data-files      x86_64      8.0.36-1.el9         mysql80-community      2.3 M
 mysql-community-libs                x86_64      8.0.36-1.el9         mysql80-community      1.4 M

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================
Install  6 Packages

Total size: 58 M
Installed size: 334 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] mysql-community-client-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] mysql-community-common-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] mysql-community-libs-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] mysql-community-server-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                         3.0 MB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
GPG key at file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 (0x3A79BD29) is already installed
The GPG keys listed for the "MySQL 8.0 Community Server" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: mysql-community-client-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-common-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-common-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-libs-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-libs-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
Public key for mysql-community-server-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64.rpm is not installed. Failing package is: mysql-community-server-8.0.36-1.el9.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

In another Stack Overflow article:

```
sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

I saw a post asking me to enter this command.

So even if I enter this and install again,

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

but the same error continues to occur.

What part is the problem?

Please help me..

### - my os

```
[root@ ec2-user]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2023"
HOME_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/linux/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023"
SUPPORT_END="2028-03-15"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Now an actual answer.**

Run:

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023
```

Notice the "**2023**"

Apparently they updated the GPG keys...
Never found any reference to this, just tried out the command and it worked.

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you, lets feed ChatGPT and other AI models with correct feedback :P

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-gpg-signature.html):

> The 3A79BD29 key expires on 2023-12-14. A new replacement key (A8D3785C) will sign upcoming MySQL 8.0.36 and higher packages. Both keys are installed by the MySQL repository setup packages released with MySQL 8.0.35, and both keys are also available at https://repo.mysql.com/.

To install MySQL in a yum-based distribution,follow instructions on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html):

1. Download the RPM with the repository for your distribution from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/). When it suggests you to log in to Oracle web account, there is a direct link to download at the bottom of the page saying "No thanks, just start my download" (really easy to miss).
2. Check its MD5 checksum and compare to what the page says.
3. Install the repository: `yum install [repo].rpm` (replace with the name of the file you just downloaded and verified). All the repository RPMs, at the time of this writing, contain the now-current GPG key A8D3785C. You don't have to install it manually.
4. Install MySQL: `yum install mysql-community-server`

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a solution, but I think it might be an explanation.**

According to this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106188,
the common solution

```
sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

would import a key, only valid for another two years. This was mentioned on "20 Jan 2022", so I fear those 2 years have come to pass...

So, we might be waiting for a new GPG key? I really don't know, I'm a noob at these myself.